# not getting data from php Api using post method

Tags: android, api, retrofit2

I am trying to get data from an API where I have to use post method as a beginner I have no experience with the post method of retrofit but from other other StackOverflow questions I am able to get the code done but when I put the username and password I am getting an error 400 as I am not able to pass data to the server 
here is the code

APIInterface:

```
public interface APIInterface {
@POST("http://tvsfit.mytvs.in/reporting/vrm/api/test_new/int/gettabledata.php")
Call<LoginResponse> createUser(@Body LoginResponse login);
}
```

APIClient:

```
class APIClient {

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://tvsfit.mytvs.in/reporting/vrm/api/test_new/int/gettabledata.php/";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

getter-setter:

```
public class LoginResponse {


@SerializedName("username")
public String UserId;
@SerializedName("FirstName")
public String FirstName;
@SerializedName("LastName")
public String LastName;
@SerializedName("ProfilePicture")
public String ProfilePicture;
@SerializedName("Password")
public String Password;
   public LoginResponse(String UserId, String Password) {
    this.UserId = UserId;
    this.Password = Password;
}
```

I am getting an error like this

`Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=http://tvsfit.mytvs.in/reporting/vrm/api/test_new/int/gettabledata.php}'

Any direction what i am doing wrong will be helpful
{
"username":"test",
"password":"123456"
}
 sample output that i must get

```
{"TABLE_DATA":"{\"data\":[[\"Tiger Nixon\",\"System Architect\",\"Edinburgh\",\"5421\",\"2011\/04\/25\",\"$320,800\"]...
```

Activity method:

```
 private void loginRetrofit2Api(String userId, String password) {
    final LoginResponse login = new LoginResponse(userId, password);
    Call<LoginResponse> call1 = apiInterface.createUser(login);
    call1.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
            Log.e("Login", response.toString());


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onFailure called ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            call.cancel();
        }
    });
}

public boolean checkValidation() {
    userId = et_Email.getText().toString();
    password = et_Pass.getText().toString();
    if (et_Email.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
        CommonMethod.showAlert("UserId Cannot be left blank", MainActivity.this);
        return false;
    } else if (et_Pass.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
        CommonMethod.showAlert("password Cannot be left blank", MainActivity.this);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

CommonMethod class:

```
public  static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context ctx) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}

public static void showAlert(String message, Activity context) {

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage(message).setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            });
    try {
        builder.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

data:[image: data recieved]

Comment: Have you tried url encoding the post url? Try `URLEncoder.encode(BASE_URL, "UTF-8");` before sending the request

Comment: no sir but its the error occurred because the username and password is not sent to the api i dont think there is any error in the that part.

Comment: May you share the code where you make the request?

Comment: @S.Souza i have added almost  all the code

Comment: Does this api has a documentation? If  so, could you share?

Comment: no there is no documentation available the only this availabe is what data you will get from this@S.Souza

Comment: This is my first time using a php Api that is why i am facing problem

Comment: Well, what's the website?

Comment: its not a website it a test sample

Comment: Well, if you use a api tester as: https://apitester.com/ you'll see the error description {"ErrorDescription":"Mandatory parameters missing","Error":400}. So, is definitely missing something in there. As I said in the answer, the body of your post should be someting like a json which contain those mandatory parameters or pass the parameters in the link

Comment: when i got the api i also thought the same thing then i did some research came to know that to test this type of api requires post method

Comment: to test the api add the advanced rest client extension and pass the username and passwor in the body section the output image is shows the result @S.Souza this is the first time i am facing this type of api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing few things wrong here.

First you need to set your base url properly.

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://tvsfit.mytvs.in/"
```

Now change path in method call accordingly. You need to set path that will be added after Base URL.

```
public interface APIInterface {
@POST("reporting/vrm/api/test_new/int/gettabledata.php")
Call<LoginResponse> createUser(@Body LoginResponse login);
}
```

Serialized names are case sensitive and you need to match them exactly with your parameter names.

```
@SerializedName("password")    //in sample request you are using password and not Password
public String Password;
```

Comment: Bro i am not able to get the data `Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK` is the log how to get the data as the following data what will i do with the responce?

Comment: Bro how i can put the data in arraylist as there is no object for the data i can convert the string but i am even getting the string value

Answer (score 0):

What you should be doing is something as:

```
public interface APIInterface {
@POST("http://tvsfit.mytvs.in/reporting/vrm/api/test_new/int/gettabledata.php")
Call<LoginResponse> createUser(@String userId, @String password);
}
```

The LoginResponse is your class to handle the response. Therefore, it doesn't make much sense passing as the argument when trying to make login.
Your would look like:

```
Call<LoginResponse> call1 = apiInterface.createUser(userId, password);
```

I might be wrong of course, so verify with the documentation in order to know exactly all the arguments.

Comment: sir but i used a constructor in the Loginresponse file that is why i did it like that

Answer (score 0):

have you test this api at **Postman** whether it is running well or not
when i test this api  at postman . it shows error **400** and shows error message **{"ErrorDescription":"Mandatory parameters missing","Error":400}** .it' you are not passing all the parameters for that api call. see this screenshot .
[api error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHY28.png)

Comment: the api is working and the pic show the output from the api